# Windows IIS8 not starting website

Tags: php, mysql, iis, windows-7

I have a windows 7 laptop and I want to set up IIS8, php, mysql to run in a development environment, but I am having trouble.

I opened IIS8, and when I click on my site "Default website" and click start, it gives an error saying "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)

Does anyone know whats going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if the port is grabbed by another process. Check https://support2.microsoft.com/kb/973094

Comment: That link is messed up. How do I check the port?

Comment: try this:  `netstat -aon | find ":80"` for port 80